# Method reference of method throwing checked exception triggers compilation error at point method reference is named

Tags: java, try-catch, method-reference, checked-exceptions

I have a bunch of methods, with similar signatures, compatible with `Function`, they each declare `throws InterruptedException`, and I put them in a list and select one by its index and call its `apply()`.

Except that I get a compiler error where the method is *named* to put in the list:

```
        final List<Function<Set<BookIdentifier>, Set<Status>>>
                submitters = List.of(
                        this::submitIndividuallySynchronously, // these are the method references
                        this::submitInBulkSynchronously,       // all 4 of them have an error message
                        this::submitIndividuallyAsynchronously,
                        this::submitInBulkAsynchronously);
        final var submitter =
                submitters.get((isIndividual() ? 0 : 1) + (isSynchronous() ? 0 : 2));
```

and writing a `try/catch` later

```
       try {
            result = submitter.apply(work.todo);
        } catch (final InterruptedException ex) {
            // do something here
        }
```

where the method reference is *used* (called) doesn't help.

The error from `javac` (SDK 17.0.5) is

```
error: incompatible thrown types InterruptedException in functional expression
```

(IntelliJ gives different errors: Each method reference has an error `Unhandled exception: java.lang.InterruptedException` and the later `catch` block has an error `Exception 'java.lang.InterruptedException' is never thrown in the corresponding try block`.)

So how can I name these method references in one place and *call* them in another?

- Besides the obvious which is to surround the naming of them with a useless `try/catch`?
- That it's an `InterruptedException` is not the issue, just needs to be any checked exception

Comment: Just figured out the answer: Declare my own `@FunctionalInterface` where the `apply` method declares `throws Exception`.  Now, question for community: Is this question sufficiently useful that it should be answered for future inquirers, or should I just delete it?

Comment: This question has been asked before in many forms, so it may not provide much value to the site. Based on that alone, I would delete it. But you also worded your question in a relatively unique way, from what I can tell. Taking that into account, I would actually leave the question up so that others who word the question similarly are directed to the duplicate.

Comment: Note there are libraries like https://github.com/pivovarit/throwing-function out there.